# ERROR Unknown App0 Marker - Expected JFIF

Tags: c#, .net-core, image-processing, jpeg, imagesharp

I am trying to convert a byte array, obtained from a Hikvision camera stream, into jpg. I use ImageSharp library.

My code is as follows:

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;

private static bool ByteArrayToFile(string fileName, byte[] byteArray)
{
    try
    {
        using (var image = Image.Load<Rgba32>(byteArray)) // <-- line 132
        {
            image.SaveAsJpeg(fileName);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ServiceLogger.LogException(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I get the following exception:

> 2023-05-15 16:44:30.2871 ERROR [1.0.0.1] Exception stack trace:    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(String
> errorMessage)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegDecoderCore.ProcessApplicationHeaderMarker(BufferedReadStream
> stream, Int32 remaining)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegDecoderCore.ParseStream(BufferedReadStream
> stream, SpectralConverter spectralConverter, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegDecoderCore.Decode[TPixel](BufferedReadStream
> stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.ImageDecoderUtilities.Decode[TPixel](IImageDecoderInternals
> decoder, Configuration configuration, Stream stream, Func`3 largeImageExceptionFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.ImageDecoderUtilities.Decode[TPixel](IImageDecoderInternals decoder, Configuration configuration, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegDecoder.Decode[TPixel](JpegDecoderOptions options, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.SpecializedImageDecoder`1.Decode[TPixel](DecoderOptions
> options, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.ImageDecoder.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<Decode>b__0(Stream s)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.ImageDecoder.<WithSeekableStream>g__PeformActionAndResetPosition|11_0[T](Stream s, Int64 position, <>c__DisplayClass11_0`1&)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.ImageDecoder.WithSeekableStream[T](DecoderOptions
> options, Stream stream, Func`2 action)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.ImageDecoder.Decode[TPixel](DecoderOptions options, Stream stream)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Decode[TPixel](DecoderOptions options, Stream stream)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.<>c__DisplayClass84_0`1.b__0(Stream
> s)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.WithSeekableStream[T](DecoderOptions
> options, Stream stream, Func`2 action)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load[TPixel](DecoderOptions options, Stream stream)    at SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load[TPixel](DecoderOptions options, ReadOnlySpan`1 data)    at
> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load[TPixel](ReadOnlySpan`1 data)    at
> DMS.Helpers.SaveImage.ByteArrayToFile(String fileName,
> Byte[] byteArray) in
> D:\source\repos\DMS\Helpers\SaveImage.cs:line
> 132 2023-05-15 16:44:30.2871 ERROR Unknown App0 Marker - Expected
> JFIF.

From my limited knowledge of the JPG format, I think the error says that the beginning of my data doesn't have the expected JFIF marker.

So I logged the first 8 bytes of my data. Here is an example:

> FF D8 FF E0 00 A5 0A 5B

Isn't this an acceptable JFIF marker for a JPG image? If yes, then why am I getting this error?

Answer (score -1):

Analyzing the first 8 bytes provided it looks like there something definitely wrong with the stream.

```bash
FF D8 - SOI marker
FF E0 - APP0 marker
00 A5 - Length in bytes (165)
0A 5B - Unknown
```

Those last two bytes are an issue, though that provided length is very long!
For jpeg you would expect the following.

`4A 46 49 46` - `JFIF` Identifier

Some badly encoded images don't provide that marker, instead only providing the APP0 extension identifier `JFXX` (`4A 46 58 58`). Support for this scenario has been [recently added to main](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/2482).

I'm really curious to see what else is happening with the stream to see if it can be worked around. Can you please post a discussion [here](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/discussions/categories/q-a) and we can have a closer look.